# Is there any other way to pay the one-time $5 fee for making Chrome Extensions, other than Google Wallet?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

The title pretty much sums my problem up. Is it possible I can use Paypal or something else instead?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about payments not programming

Comment: @greg-449 This is about an app distribution platform, so it's relevant.

Comment: Why can't you use Google Wallet?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this help](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/187591) article, apparently not.

If you want a reasoning for this:

The developer signup fee is there to verify your identity, not to milk money off developers. This is why it's a token $5 amount.

Paypal is a semi-anonymous (as far as sellers are concerned) payment system. Google Wallet would only allow a credit/debit card that has your name, and your identity is verified by the issuing bank.